# Why I get error Invalid number ORA-01722:

Tags: sql, oracle

I am a little bit confusing and have no idea how to solve this problem. I have column in  table Quantity which store `Time` value.
I want to create a following story. If  I have for example

```
Quantity
8:00
8:00
```

It needs to SUM() this two and in output I need to get `16` `HOURS`
Second think, it needs to take last two number `:00` and add to HOURS.
This is what I do so far

```
SELECT 
           (SUM(SUBSTR(A.Quantity, ':', 1)) + TRUNC((SUM(SUBSTR(A.Quantity, ':', -1)) / 60),0)),  ':'  ,
             MOD(SUM(SUBSTR(A.Quantity, ':' , -1)), 60)
                    AS TOTAL_SUM FROM (
                    SELECT 
                        ata.ATAID AS AtaId, ata.ProjectID, ata.StartDate, ataAW.Quantity
                    FROM 
                        ata
                    INNER JOIN 
                        weekly_report
                    ON
                        weekly_report.ataId = ata.ATAID
                    INNER JOIN 
                        ata_articles  ataAW 
                    ON 
                        ataAW.wrId = weekly_report.id 
                    WHERE 
                        ata.ATAID = 10987
                    AND 
                        ataAW.type = 1
                    OR 
                        ataAW.type = 2
                    OR
                        ataAW.type = 3
                    AND
                        (weekly_report.status != 3 AND weekly_report.status != 4)
                    AND
                    (
                        weekly_report.year < (SELECT year FROM weekly_report WHERE id = 89)
                        OR
                        (
                            weekly_report.year <= (SELECT year FROM weekly_report WHERE id = 89)
                            AND
                            weekly_report.week <= (SELECT week FROM weekly_report WHERE id = 89)
                        )
                    )
                ) A 
                 group by A.AtaId
```

So far better explanation, when I run first part of query I need to get something like

```
SELECT 
                    CONCAT(
                    -- extract hours froAm time and add minutes converted to hours
                   (SUM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(aa.Quantity, ':', 1)) + TRUNCATE((SUM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(aa.Quantity, ':', -1)) / 60),0))
                  --  , ':',
                    -- extract minutes from time and find reminder (modulo)*/
                   -- LPAD((SUM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(aa.Quantity, ':', -1)) % 60), 2, 0)
                ) AS W_TOTAL_SUM 
                FROM 
                    ata_articles aa
                INNER JOIN
                    weekly_report wr
                ON
                    aa.wrId = wr.id
                WHERE
                    aa.wrId = 69
                AND
                    aa.type = 1


TOTAL_SUM
16
```

And when I run second part

```
SELECT 
                    CONCAT(
                    -- extract hours froAm time and add minutes converted to hours
                  -- (SUM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(aa.Quantity, ':', 1)) + TRUNCATE((SUM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(aa.Quantity, ':', -1)) / 60),0))
                  --  , ':',
                    -- extract minutes from time and find reminder (modulo)*/
                   LPAD((SUM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(aa.Quantity, ':', -1)) % 60), 2, 0)
                ) AS W_TOTAL_SUM 
                FROM 
                    ata_articles aa
                INNER JOIN
                    weekly_report wr
                ON
                    aa.wrId = wr.id
                WHERE
                    aa.wrId = 69
                AND
                    aa.type = 1
```

I get output

```
TOTAL_SUM
00
```

Can someone guide me and tell me how to solve this issue since I try every solution but unfortunetlly doesn't work. And here is what I try so far, but I always get message

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number





SELECT 
           (SUM(SUBSTR(A.Quantity, ':', 1)) + TRUNC((SUM(SUBSTR(A.Quantity, ':', -1)) / 60),0)),  ':'  ,
             MOD(SUM(SUBSTR(A.Quantity, ':' , -1)), 60)
                    AS TOTAL_SUM FROM (
                    SELECT 
                        ata.ATAID AS AtaId, ata.ProjectID, ata.StartDate, ataAW.Quantity
                    FROM 
                        ata
                    INNER JOIN 
                        weekly_report
                    ON
                        weekly_report.ataId = ata.ATAID
                    INNER JOIN 
                        ata_articles  ataAW 
                    ON 
                        ataAW.wrId = weekly_report.id 
                    WHERE 
                        ata.ATAID = 10987
                    AND 
                        ataAW.type = 1
                    OR 
                        ataAW.type = 2
                    OR
                        ataAW.type = 3
                    AND
                        (weekly_report.status != 3 AND weekly_report.status != 4)
                    AND
                    (
                        weekly_report.year < (SELECT year FROM weekly_report WHERE id = 89)
                        OR
                        (
                            weekly_report.year <= (SELECT year FROM weekly_report WHERE id = 89)
                            AND
                            weekly_report.week <= (SELECT week FROM weekly_report WHERE id = 89)
                        )
                    )
                ) A 
                 group by A.AtaId
```

**UPDATE**

I get output error message

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 267 Column: 19



SELECT ( EXTRACT( DAY FROM duration ) * 24 + EXTRACT( HOUR FROM duration ) )
       || ':'
       || TO_CHAR( EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM DURATION ), 'FM00' )
       || ' HOURS' AS duration
FROM   (
  SELECT NUMTODSINTERVAL(SUM( SUBSTR( quantity, 1, INSTR( quantity, ':' ) - 1 ) ),'HOUR')
         + NUMTODSINTERVAL(SUM( SUBSTR( quantity, INSTR( quantity, ':' ) + 1 ) ), 'MINUTE' ) 
         AS duration
  FROM (
    SELECT ata.ATAID AS AtaId, ata.ProjectID, ata.StartDate, ataAW.Quantity
    FROM   ata
           INNER JOIN weekly_report 
           ON weekly_report.ataId = ata.ATAID
           INNER JOIN ata_articles ataAW 
           ON ataAW.wrId = weekly_report.id
           INNER JOIN (SELECT week, year FROM weekly_report WHERE id = 89 ) b
           ON ( weekly_report.year < b.year OR ( weekly_report.year = b.year AND weekly_report.week <= b.week ))
    WHERE  ata.ATAID = 10987
    AND    ataAW.type IN ( 1, 2, 3 )
    AND    weekly_report.status NOT IN ( 3, 4 )
    ))
  group by A.AtaId
```

Here is what I get as output when I execute following code

```
DURATION
 :HOURS
```

Comment: The right parenthesis you're missing is at the end. Also, use `ataAW.type IN ( 1, 2, 3 ) AND weekly_report.status NOT IN ( 3, 4 )` and you can `JOIN ( SELECT week, year FROM weekly_report WHERE id = 89 )` rather than using multiple almost identical queries. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4073c4e5f191f71588f73dcc67daf75c)

Comment: ORA-00904: "DURATION": invalid identifier

Comment: That's because you renamed it `TOTAL_SUM` and not `duration`.

Comment: Another error message ORA-00904: "A"."ATAID": invalid identifier

Comment: It is your code, what did you mean when you wrote `GROUP BY A.AtaId`? If you are asking about the db<>fiddle, then I dropped the `A` table alias, you can just use `GROUP BY AtaId`.

Comment: Yes, It works now. But in output I get    :HOURS

Comment: [Edit] your question with a [MRE] including: DDL statements for your tables, DML statements for some sample data that replicates the problem; and your expected output for that sample data. You probably have a `NULL` value in your table but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the (slightly more complicated) sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Quantity ) AS
SELECT '8:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '7:30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0:30' FROM DUAL;
```

Then you can use string functions to get the hour and minute parts and sum those and then convert the totals to an interval (so you don't end up with `15:60 HOURS`) and then format the output:

```sql
SELECT ( EXTRACT( DAY FROM duration ) * 24
       + EXTRACT( HOUR FROM duration )
       )
       || ':'
       || TO_CHAR( EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM DURATION ), 'FM00' )
       || ' HOURS' AS duration
FROM   (
  SELECT NUMTODSINTERVAL(
           SUM( SUBSTR( quantity, 1, INSTR( quantity, ':' ) - 1 ) ),
           'HOUR'
         )
         +
         NUMTODSINTERVAL(
           SUM( SUBSTR( quantity, INSTR( quantity, ':' ) + 1 ) ),
           'MINUTE'
         ) AS duration
  FROM   table_name
);
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> | DURATION    |
> | :---------- |
> | 16:00 HOURS |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e975f5dd0e36d40b35ef6d4173fc02c1)*